# Only allow certain keypresses

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a summary box and once it reaches 300 characters i dont want the user to be able to type in any more. The problem is, with my code, that with the keydown function I cannot then backspace, delete, ctrl+a(select all) if I want to change the content. Is there a way to prevent text from entering but allowing keys to be pressed for those purposes?

```
function char_count(){
    limit = 300;
    current = $('#property_summary').val().length;
    $('#char_count').html(current + '/' + limit);
}

$('#property_summary').keyup(function(){
    char_count();
});

$('#property_summary').keydown(function(e){
    if( $('#property_summary').val().length == 300 ){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: use `e.keyCode` to exclude backspace,ctrl + a , ...

Comment: Allow the length to go over the limit, but check the length after a keypress, then if it's over the limit, truncate to the maximum allowed length.

Comment: You should prevent the user to input more than x character. You should instead said how much character he has and tell him "you have x number of character beyond the limit". People often copy/paste text and it is anoying when it doesnt copy the entire site. Also, the only good way to block to a limit is to use HTML5 maxlength. wich is not supported. Programming it is way harder than just check if you pressed backspace. User can select a part of text and start writing (hence removing character). Also using a "block" cut the idea of the user. It is easier to write full text and erase some part--

Comment: (had too much characters) than rethink your entire text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help?

```
<textarea maxlength="300">
    Enter text here...
</textarea>
```

You must remember about verification on server side using for example PHP: strlen() function.

**Few more words based on comments:**
We should do as much as we can, to **keep the standarts**. The standart for operating system: CTRL-C is used for copying, CTRL+V for pasting. **If someone is overwriting this settings, he is almost always wrong**. *Javascript is used for helping and not for being nerve-wracking.*

If maxlength is set for 300 hundred, make a little annotation: warning, you cannot enter more then 300 characters, please correct Your text.
There is no need for spoil, queer and destroy user text. 
This is my opinion, if someone has got another (and I see that yes), please write a comment.

PS. Max length is ADDITIONAL functionality in that case. So let the browsers "catch up" specification, and remember about server side verification.

Comment: Who says he's using PHP?  And w3schools should not be relied on

Comment: He said "for example"

Comment: No-one. But server side verification is ALWAYS needed. You can't rely on Javascript only. And max-length property is additional functionality, so there is no need to do anything more than this.

Comment: But it's not germane to the question.  Do we have to run around saying "sanitize your data inputs" on every single database related question?    I would get pretty annoyed at a passenger who constantly told me to hit the brakes at every red light I approached while driving.  Some things do not warrant constant repeating.

Comment: Update with a little more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest you using something like this:

```
$('#property_summary').keyup(function () {

         var balchar = 300;
         if ($('#property_summary').val().length > balchar) {
             $('#property_summary').val($('#property_summary').val().substring(0, balchar))
         }
    });
```

This will remove the characters more than 300. also backspace and delete work intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#property_summary').keydown(function(e){
    if( $('#property_summary').val().length == 300 && e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 46 && !e.ctrlKey && !(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 65)){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```